# How to change text in SecureSocial

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm wondering how to change text in SecureSocial views... I've created file `messages.en` in the `conf` directory... but it does not work. If I want my text and other stuff like copyright notice, shall I create my own custom views?

Thanks.

Comment: Putting a messages file in the conf directory of your app should work.  Try without the .en extension and see if it works. Also, make sure the language your browser is sending matches one of your files. It could be that it's defaulting to english because you did not provide the right extension.

Comment: Thanks... but I had to customize the views anyway :-) Just another question... What's about the password salt? It looks like SecureSocial does not generate it by default... Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: It does. Check BCryptPasswordHasher.

Comment: @j3d You should mark this question as resolved if it the case. Thx.