# SecureSocial Plugin for Play: Messages (i18n)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1, message, securesocial

I have created a subpackage of views in order to customize the default look of securesocial's templates. (I have used https://github.com/ngarera/securesocial-custom-views-sample as an example and basically copied the relevant files)

There are two i18n-files (messages.en, messages.de) in my /conf folder.
Viewing the main page confirms that the messages.en is correctly used.

However, when calling /login (and therefore displaying the custom template), no messages-key is correctly looked up - instead only the key itself (e.g. "auth.login") is displayed, when really it should show "Login".

I have seen a similar request at Stackoverflow ([How to change text in SecureSocial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696385/how-to-change-text-in-securesocial)) where it was stated to remove the .en file extension. Doing that will show the correct Message...but creating one messages file is not really the point of internationalization...

I have confirmed that my browser sends the correct language (http://www.mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp?bhcp=1) so messages.de should work...(which it does when I open a self-made controller - only the custom-securesocial-view is not working...)

Does anybody have similar problems?
And why does the localization work for securesocial's messages?

Regards,
David

PS: using Play 2.1.3, Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues in the SecureSocial code that prevented i18n from working properly.

This has been fixed and is currently available in the master-SNAPSHOT version because a stable version with those changes has not been released yet.